# Parsing Parenthesis using stack template class in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, stack, parentheses

I have a homework and its just bugging for the last 2 days, I've been doing exactly what the pseudo code and still haven't got it right yet. 
For example, if I put in "mike]" or "mike]123", my program will crash, due to the stack is empty...From what I observe, the program will crash when:
- The stack is empty
- And there is a close parenthesis
PS: with the help of us2012, I can fix the crash problem. However, the result is not right.
Instead of printing out "invalid", it outputs "valid"

:(

Here is the pseudo code from my professor:

```
def parse_parenthesis(str):
    stack = create a new empty stack of OpenParen objects
    for i from 0 to str.size() - 1:
        if str[i] is an open parenthesis
            stack.push(new OpenParen(str[i]))
        else if str[i] is not a close parenthesis:
            # str[i] is not a parenthesis of any kind, so ignore it
            continue
        # otherwise str[i] must be a close parenthesis, try to
        # match it with the most recent open paren, on the top
        # of the stack
        else if stack is empty
        return false;
        else if stack.peek() is of the same type as str[i]:
        # close properly
        stack.pop()
        else
        return false;
    if stack is not empty
        return false;
    else
        return true
```

and here is what I have so far:

.cpp file

```
bool ParenMatching(const string& s, unique_ptr<string>& output)
{
    unique_ptr<OpenParen> stack(new OpenParen);

    bool validOpen, validClose, valid;
    bool match; //haveCloseParen;
    /*string unMatch = "Unmatch";
    string unExpected = "Unexpected close paren";
    string noError = "No Error";*/

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        // check if its open parenthesis
        validOpen = stack->IsOpenParen(s[i]);
        // check if its close parenthesis
        validClose = stack->IsCloseParen(s[i]);

        // if there is open paren, push into the stack
        if(validOpen)
            stack->PushObj(s[i]);
        else if(!validClose)
        {
            continue;
        }
            else if(stack->GetObj().IsEmpty())
            valid = false;      
        else if(match = IsMatchParen(s[i], stack))
            stack->PopObj();            
        else
            valid = false;
    }

    if(!stack->GetObj().IsEmpty())
        valid = false;
    else
        valid = true;
    return valid;
}

bool IsMatchParen(const char c, const unique_ptr<OpenParen>& stack)
{   
    bool valid;
    if(c == ')' && stack->PeekObj() == '(')
        valid = true;
    else if (c == ']' && stack->PeekObj() == '[')
        valid = true;
    else if (c == '}' && stack->PeekObj() == '{')
        valid = true;
    else if (c == '>' && stack->PeekObj() == '<')
        valid = true;
    else
        valid = false;
    return valid;
}
```

OpenParen.cpp

```
// Check if its open paren
bool OpenParen::IsOpenParen(const char c)
{
    bool isOpen;
    if(c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{' || c == '<')
        isOpen = true;
    else
        isOpen = false;
    return isOpen;
}

// check if its close paren
bool OpenParen::IsCloseParen(const char c)
{
    bool isClose;
    if(c == ')' || c == ']' || c == '}' || c == '>')
        isClose = true;
    else
        isClose = false;
    return isClose;
}
```

Comment: That's really a bit too much code to expect us to debug all of it. Please try to localize the issue and make your problem description more detailed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did remove some code that I think it will not be relevant to my question. Please take a look and see what I did wrong.

Comment: `OpenParem::IsOpenParen` could be implemented as just `return c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{' || c == '<';`, and it shouldn't be an instance method at all and instead just a function. Same about `IsCloseParen`.

Comment: I agree, unless there's more to this that requires some sort of object to maintain state I'd implement it as free functions.  I love to see people using smart pointers, but the use of `unique_ptr` in this case is completely unnecessary and just complicates things for no reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gcc 4.7.3: g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x parens.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool isOpen(char c) {
  return c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{' || c == '<'; }

bool isClose(char c) {
  return c == ')' || c == ']' || c == '}' || c == '>'; }

bool isMatch(char c1, char c2) {
  return (c1 == '(' && c2 == ')')
      || (c1 == '[' && c2 == ']')
      || (c1 == '{' && c2 == '}')
      || (c1 == '<' && c2 == '>'); }

bool parse(const std::string& s) {
  std::stack<std::string::value_type> stk;

  for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
    if (isOpen(s[i])) { stk.push(s[i]); }
    else if (isClose(s[i])) {
      if (!stk.empty() && isMatch(stk.top(), s[i])) { stk.pop(); }
      else { return false; } } }

  return stk.empty(); }

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> ptests = {
      "", "()", "()()", "(())", "a(a)a" };
  std::vector<std::string> ftests = {
      "(", ")", ")(", ")()(", "))((" };

  for (const auto& t : ptests) {
    if (!parse(t)) { std::cout << "fail: " << t << std::endl; } }

  for (const auto& t : ftests) {
    if (parse(t)) { std::cout << "fail: " << t << std::endl; } }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, we have not learned vector and neither can we use stack header file :((, but I'll keep that in mind as a suggestion in the future ;)

Comment: std::vector is only used for my test cases, it is not part of the solution. And I imagine the difference between std::stack and the stack you are using is pretty small.

Answer (score 3):

One important thing you should keep in mind about C++ : Multiple `else if`s do **not** live at the same level. That's because `else if` is not a single entity, it's an `else` that belongs to the preceding statement and an `if`that begins a new statement, so

```
if (cond1)
 a();
else if (cond 2)
 b();
else if (cond 3)
 c();
else
 d();
```

is actually

```
if (cond1)
 a();
else { 
  if (cond 2)
   b();
  else {
    if (cond 3)
     c();
    else
     d();
  }
}
```

Therefore, your check whether the stack is empty needs to be **before** the check whether the current close parens matches the top of the stack. Otherwise, your program will try to examine the top of the stack when it's empty, and that results in a crash.

---

Also, setting `valid = false` is not the right thing to do when you find a condition that indicates a non-match. The loop will still continue and can reset `valid` to `true` in a later iteration. You need to immediately `return false`, as you can already see in your pseudocode.

Comment: thanks for your input. I did not know that, I always thought that they're all the same level... 
PS: My program would not crash anymore. However, its output is wrong for case like. Instead of "invalid", it prints out "valid" :(((.

Comment: When: the stack is empty AND there is a close parenthesis AND there is still some more characters left in the string

Comment: @user Did you *read* my answer? The suggestion is right there in the last sentence. I'm not going to tell you exactly which letter to put where, this is homework after all :)

Comment: I just don't know how to get out of the for-loop while the iteration is still going and keep the value as false....anyway, thanks for your help. I'll try my best to figure out

PS: I try to put "break;" but it didn't work :(( guess I have to try harder

Comment: @user You said you tried `break`, why didn't you try `return false;` as it says in my answer ;) ?

Comment: so you should not set valid = false/true in a for-loop, since the iteration could change your value; instead, just return false/true. Am I correct ?

Comment: No, that's completely incorrect. It depends on what you want from it. In a situation where something invalid can become valid again, you don't want to `return false`. In *your* situation, you certainly do *not* want to `return true` *inside* the loop. Read about what `return`, `continue` and `break` do and you'll find out how they work.

Comment: thanks for your help. I will definitely look for more info about those.